# Java Thread doesn't work when trying to change variable value

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

I'm experimenting a bit with Java Threads and I'm trying to use a Thread to change some variable called `number` in my class by a Thread in another class. 
But apparently it is not working, I always get the 0 from when I started my value, maybe somebody could tell me why.

This is my first class:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public int number = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest Adding = new ThreadTest();
        Adding.addingOnes();
        System.out.println(Adding.number);
    }

    public void addingOnes() {
        Runnable thread1 = new ThreadClassPlus();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1);
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add() {
        number++;
    }
}
```

And my second class for the Thread:

```
public class ThreadClassPlus extends ThreadTest implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            add();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It never makes sense to join a thread immediately after starting it...  Ok, maybe it will help you to _learn_ something about threads, but it would never make sense to do that in a real program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `ThreadTest` instance and your `ThreadClassPlus` instance are different objects.  Your thread is incrementing `number` in the latter instance, but your `main` method is reading the value of `number` from the former.  Naturally, the former doesn't have the value of the latter.

The threading is working fine.  The problem is in how you are using it.

Here is a corrected version:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    public int number = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest adding = new ThreadTest();
        adding.addingOnes();
        System.out.println(adding.number);
    }

    public void addingOnes()
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add() {
        number++;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            add();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note carefully the various style changes I made.  Java style is important.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you are increasing value of variable `number` belonging to object `thread1`, while printing value of variable `number` belonging to object `Adding`.

Just printout proper variable value and you will see expected result:

```
    System.out.println(((ThreadClassPlus)thread1).number);
```

And BTW, please, do not name variables starting with uppercase, this is very bad style: <strike>A</strike>dding => **a**dding.